# Combining multiple column vectors into larger column vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I am starting off with 32 column vectors such as [1;2;3;4]. All of them are in this format and I would like to combine them into 2 different column vectors like so:

```
chan0=[adc0;adc2;adc4...]
chan2=[adc1;adc3;adc5...]
```

So chan0 would look something like:

```
[0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;...]
```

I've tried

```
for i=0:31
    data_in = dlmread(['raw\adc',num2str(i),'.txt']);
    if(mod(i,2)==0)
        chan0=chan0+data_in;
    else
        chan2=chan0+data_in;
    end
end
```

First off I obviously get an error saying chan0 is undefined, so what should I define chan0 and chan2 as?

Second, even then would this code give me the vectors I want?

Third, might as well as while I'm here, to write both chan0 and chan2 to a txt file it would be

```
dlmwrite('raw\chan0.txt',chan0);
dlmwrite('raw\chan2.txt',chan2);
```

right?

Thank you,
Tyler

Comment: Why do you have the `dlmread()` inside the loop? It seems to read from the same file across all loop iterations.

Comment: Sorry fixed that. I was just trying to make sure it was reading in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this-

```
chan0=[];
chan2=[];
for i=0:31
    data_in = dlmread(['raw\adc',num2str(i),'.txt']);
    if(mod(i,2)==0)
        chan0=[chan0;data_in];
    else
        chan2=[chan2;data_in];
    end
end
```

Comment: that gives a column vector with 64 zeros then the data, which I guess it pretty easy to get rid of. Thank you!

Comment: I removed the `chan0=zeros(64,1)` since that was giving wrong result, instead you can simply do `chan0=[]` as explained above.